# while post the text to tumblr i get the msg not 401 not authorized

Tags: android, authentication, authorization, tumblr

I'm using the following code to post the text to tumblr in my Android application :

```
public class Snippet {
    HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + blogname.getText().toString() + ".tumblr.com/post");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "text"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", body));
    try 
    {
        hpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
    {
        debug += e.toString();
    }
    consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
    try 
    {
        consumer.sign(hpost);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) 
    {
        debug += e.toString();
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) 
    {
        debug += e.toString();
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) 
    {
        debug += e.toString();
    }
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse resp = null;
    try 
    {
        resp = client.execute(hpost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        debug += e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        debug += e.toString();
    }
    String result = null;
    try {
        result = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
    } catch (ParseException e) 
    {
        debug += e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        debug += e.toString();
    }
}
```

Then I get the following result :

```
{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

Did I miss anything ? I have the right access token and secret key.

Comment: did you got solution of this issue ? i am facing same.

Answer (score 0):

check your title, body or blog name if it's equals null your respons will be  401

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a blog on the tumblr then you will be able to post on that blog.You manulaly need to create a blog then you post on that blog..

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + blogname.getText().toString() + ".tumblr.com/post");
```

Replace `.tumblr.com/post` by `.tumblr.com/posts`